# Get server data using web services

Tags: android, sqlite, web-services, android-sqlite, retrofit

I want to get the data from server database using retrofit library and save it to sqlite database in android. I cannot find any tutorials regarding this problem. Which method i should follow to solve this problem

Comment: Go _youtube_ search **resocoder weather app**

Comment: Suggest me in Java not Kotlin

Answer (score 0):

The better aproach by my experience is using **MVVM** for a good code structure and clean calls to the web service. I suggest to use **Retrofit** with **Live Data** for the web service, **Kotlin Coroutines** for threading and **ROOM Database** for SQLite management. You can find this kind of tutorials and more in [Ray Wenderlich tutorials](https://www.raywenderlich.com/). Also search in this plattform for another modules of Android architecture, it will be useful for better improvements.

Comment: Any suggestions for Java because i am not using Kotlin

Comment: In that case you can use RxJava for threading instead of Kotlin Coroutines. The other things are in java explained [here](https://medium.com/@eslam.hussein/dominate-remote-local-data-with-rx-retrofit-room-mvp-f2b13a0ac27b) and a video example [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JOinUZLs3l8). Also i suggest the use of Kotlin for Android Development.